# Take only part of matrix in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

given a matrix A, e.g. `A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])` and two lists one of row indices and one of column indices, e.g. `row=(0,1), column=(0,2)` I want to extract the corresponding rows and columns of matrix A in python, so in this example I want the result to be `np.array([[1, 3], [5,7]))`. I know how to adress a single entry in a matrix, but not all within a list, moreover I am always loosing the structure. So far the best result I got was with `A[row, column]`, which does not return all indices listed, only `A=np.array(([1,7]))`. I also know that there exists a slicing command, but this only works for consecutive rows and columns which is not the case.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
A[np.array(row)[:,None], column]
```

output:

```
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 7]])
```

intermediate:

```
np.array(row)[:,None]

array([[0],
       [1]])
```

Comment: Also, it's possible to use `np.newaxis`: `A[row[:, np.newaxis], column]`

Comment: np.newaxis is just an alias for None (to make axis expansion more readable)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```py
np.array([[A[r][c] for c in column] for r in row]) # array([[1, 3], [5, 7]])
```

Comment: two drawbacks, as you loop this will be slow on large arrays, and you cannot use this to index/assign the existing array, this creates a new one ;)